# Soccer table of scores match

Tags: c++

So basically I'm trying to solve a problem that calculated the football team ranks which is in a matriz.

First of all, you enter an integer number which tells you number of teams.

Then in the next lines, you enter the goals in a matris. **The a[i][j] element says the number of goals team i did to team j.**
Win = 3 points

Tie = 1 point for both

Lose = 0 Points

The higher the points are, the better the rank would be. The team with higher goal difference gets a better rank in case its points are equal to someone else. (I could not write the goal difference part).

So if you enter the goals like this, the first line would be team a, second is b, etc..

```
3 //Means 3 teams will be entered
0  1  2
0  0  0
3  1  0
```

I have problem at this part when I wanna say the team ranks with a, b, etc. using ASCII code. (+ the goal difference part)

Any helps?

The code I tried to write, but it shows weird characters:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    int goals[28][28], scores[28]{}, goaldiff[28]{}, t = 0, Final[28];
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> goals[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i == j) continue;
            if (goals[i][j] > goals[j][i])
                scores[i]+= 3;
            if (goals[i][j] == goals[j][i])
                scores[i]++;

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (i == j) break;
            goaldiff[i] += goals[i][j] - goals[j][i];
        }

    }
    //Sorts score array and place them in Final array.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

                if (scores[i] > scores[j])
                    t++;
            }
            Final[t] = scores[i];
            t = 0;
    }
    for (int k = n-1; n > 0; k--){
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (Final[k] == scores[i]){
                    char team = 'a';
                    team = (int)team + i;
                    cout << team;
                    break;
                }
            }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output (For example if team i = 3 is #1, team i = 1 is #2, team i = 2 #3):

```
cab
```

C represents the i = 3 team of the matris (with 3 1 0 goals).

A represents the i = 1 team of the matris (with 0 1 2 goals).

B represents the i = 2 team of the matris (with 0 0 0 goals).

NOTE: The `i=j` elements of this matris is 0 (a[2][2] for example), because a team doesn't play with itself (Team 2 doesn't play with itself), so `i=j` elements should be disregarded.

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of the "2", it does not seem to match your description.

Comment: @Yunnosch What 2?

Comment: First row, third column, of your 3x3 value sample. Search for "2", all the other occurrences of that digit are within "28"s.

Comment: @Yunnosch 
2 is a[1][3] element of the matris. It means team [1] did 2 goals to team [3].

Comment: So those values are not corresponding to "Win = 3 points

Tie = 1 point for both

Lose = 0 Points" ?

Comment: However, my code starts with i=0 and j=0.

Comment: I see. I just confused the meanings because of the immediate proximity and the "improvable" formatting.

Comment: what is the output and what is the expected output?

Comment: @Yunnosch Nope. The matris only shows the number of goals. But Win/Tie/Lose can be calculated. For example: k= a[2][1] - a[1][2] (The number of goals that team 2 did to team 1 - the number of goals team 1 did to team 2).
If k > 0, team 2 is the winner, if k = 0 tie and if k < 0 team 1 is the winner.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Edited the post, check the end.

Comment: what is the output of the code you have now?

Comment: Tactical note: Most of the time the goal differential doesn't come into play, and when it does it is only relevant for 2 teams. There is no point to computing it for every match-up just in case it's needed. Save you a bit of code and computing time.

Comment: is it possible the your problem is only to get character `a`, `b`, `c` by some integer arithmetics on their ascii code? If thats the case you could remove all the rest from the question

Comment: did you try to print the index of the teams first to see that your algorithm is correct?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Well, most probably yes. Because most of the loops work fine. it was checked to Final array loop and it was fine. The problem is from the last loop which should print the results.

Comment: `team += (int)team + (k-n+1);` can you explain this, operator by operator?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Well, that line was edited. In that line, I tried to print a char. So let's say I wanna print c, a, b (which means team c is #1, team a is #2 and team b is#3). I tried using ASCII code to print it. In my example, team c wins the league and character c should be printed. (Team c is i=2 of the matris).
So if I wanna print c first I should say 'a' + 2.
Final array is made the sorted array of scores.

Comment: Ok now this line. `for (int k = n-1; n > 0; k--){`. When does the loop terminate?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a secret what your code prints and I am too lazy to manually get the input. Anyhow, this:

```
 team += (int)team + (k-n+1);
```

cannot be correct. It is equivalent to:

```
 team = team + team + (k-n+1);
```

which is

```
 team = 2*team + (k-n+1);
```

If `team` starts with the ascii-code for `'a'` then after this calculation it will be far off.

What you should have done is: print the index of the team to see that the rest of your code does what it should. Pretty printing should be only of concern when you know that algorithm is ok.

Comment: That line should be like:
`team = (int)team + i;`
It fixes the weird character part, but it prints many a/b/c characters.